# Firebase cloud functions sync nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Why am I always getting in my firebase console "Promise { pending }" ?

[image]
I'm pretty sure I correctly use the promise concept with the ".then".. what is wrong in my function ? (edited with the Alexandr Biship)

```
exports.GenerateLiveGameIfAllPlayerReady = functions.database.ref("games/lobby/{pushId}/playerList/{playerId}").onUpdate(event => {
//Get the object of the game then put it in the Live games node
const transfertNewLiveGame = event.data.ref.parent.parent.once('value').then(snap => {
    return snap.val();
}).then(() => {
    console.log(transfertNewLiveGame);
    console.log(event.params.pushId);

    return admin.database().ref('games/live').update({
        [event.params.pushId]: transfertNewLiveGame
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, trigger function requires `Promise` but you're missing `return`. so your code should be like this.

```
exports.GenerateLiveGameIfAllPlayerReady = functions.database.ref("games/lobby/{pushId}/playerList/{playerId}").onUpdate(event => {

      return event.data.ref.parent.parent.once('value', function(snap) {

            return admin.database().ref('games/live').update({
                [event.params.pushId]: snap.val()
            });

      });
```

Comment: Good point ! But I still get the error in the console. I just edited my post with your modification.

Comment: just edited my post. please check and let me know how it works.

Comment: Like a charm!
I still don't understand why it didn't work with the "const TransfertNewLiveGame. " Actually, I did almost a copy-paste from the video tutorial from Jenn at : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Nvm thanks! I was on this problem at least 8 hours before I asked...

Comment: Glad to hear about that. as you said, it requires Promise object but actually you were returning resolved result before. `.then()`